# Jquery UI - Dynamically added resizable & draggable divs are going outside the containment

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-resizable

Pls go through the demo link of fiddle. When the user adds new text to the ParentDIV, then the newly added layer is going beyond the size of the parent layer.

Try click the button 3 or 4 times, and you will notice that the new text layer will be outside the parent layer..

Can we confine the newly added layers inside the layer ? Is there any logic present with the JqueryUI controls ?

Please help.

[jsFiddle Demo link](http://jsfiddle.net/e2yfC/12/)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.dragClass {
   display: inline-block;
   float: left
}

$(".dragClass")
    .draggable({
        stack: "div",            
        cursor      : "move",
        delay       : 100,
        scroll      : false,
        containment : "parent",
        refreshPositions: true,
        scroll: true
    })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e2yfC/18/

Comment: thanks for the try, but not it is showing scrollbars and still able to add the text and push beyond the area... I dont want scrollbars..Can we avoid the DOM content push?

Answer (score 0):

Instead i opted for another solution that is set the position of the newly added div i.e. top and left position to it. This way, the newly created div or images will stick at one place say top:10; left:10.